# Do you know of any sample code showing how to draw a mind map using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I've searched on the web for a code sample for creating a mind map using `<canvas>`. I've found that the infoVis toolkit samples use direct json for their mind map. I have a pre-constructed json and it will be a problem to convert it to the required format (id, children etc).

What I need is a way to convert a hierarchy of items into a map like visualization. Any help/ hint is appreciated

Comment: Would writing code to convert your JSON to their required JSON format *really* be harder than writing custom code to create a mind map from your JSON? (I’m entirely unfamiliar with infoVis’ required JSON format, so maybe it would.)

Answer (score 2):

See if `d3.js`'s sample gallery has anything that might help you:

http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/

Answer (score 1):

Mindmap Using jQuery. Check it here.

http://www.jqueryrain.com/2013/04/mindmup-mapjs-zero-friction-mind-map-canvas-with-jquery/